# jquery: show a selected text on an input

Tags: jquery

I need to display a selected text from a list on an input with jquery.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tea</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" value="Text selected">
```

Comment: We need to see your honest attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a name for text input so other text input not affected

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('ul li a').click(function(e) 
 { 
       $("#drink_name").val($(this).text());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tea</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" value="Text selected" id="drink_name">
```

Comment: You are welcome.If you don't mind if you think its works perfect then could you accept my answer.